# Uma PDO Exception ocorre quando é utilizado localhost como host

Tags: php, linux, pdo, ubuntu

Considere a seguinte classe adaptadora `DbAdapterMySQL` que estende a classe `PDO`:

```
class DbAdapterMySQL extends \PDO implements DbInterface
{

    public function __construct(array $config)
    {
        $dsn = "mysql:dbname={$config['dbname']};host={$config['host']}";

        //A próxima linha é a 13
        parent::__construct($dsn, $config['username'], $config['passwd']);
    }

    //...
}
```

Repare que para o método construtor é passado um array com as configurações de acesso a base de dados com a seguinte estrutura:

```
db = MySQL
dbname = teste
username = 'root'
passwd = 'root'
host = 127.0.0.1
```

Até aqui tudo funciona perfeitamente, porém se substituir o valor do índice `host` por `localhost` o seguinte erro é retornado:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory' in /home/filipe/projects/teste/lib/vendor/Testes/Db/Adapter/DbAdapterMySQL.php:13 Stack trace: #0 
>   in /home/filipe/projects/teste/lib/vendor/Testes/Db/Adapter/DbAdapterMySQL.php on line 13

Por que ocorre o erro ao utilizar o `localhost`?

Comment: Está usando linux ou mac?

Comment: @rray linux, vou adicionar a tag.

Comment: [Isso](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2412064/1342547) parece estar na solução do problema, pq bem é estranho tentar conectar no banco e receber uma exception dizendo arquivo não encontrado.

Comment: @rray era esse mesmo o problema. A primeira parte da resposta basta, de alterar o `php.ini`. Queres postar a resposta ou faço eu?

Comment: Não tenho como testar, cria ai uma resposta com os detalhes :), só cita o link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parece que o problema está relacionado a conexão do PHP com o MySQL.

Pelo que entendi, quando utilizamos `localhost` como host, o PHP utiliza socket para se conectar ao MySQL, diferente de quando utilizamos `127.0.0.1` no qual a conexão é feita através de TCP/IP.

Se você utiliza algum sistema baseado em Linux, deve existir um arquivo de configuração `my.cnf` que é usado para configurar o MySQL.

No meu caso como estou a usar o Ubuntu, o arquivo se encontra no diretório `/etc/mysql/` e existi uma linha como esta:

```
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

O PHP precisa usar o mesmo arquivo e no meu caso não era o mesmo que o MySQL utilizava.

Para corrigir o problema, alterei o `php.ini` adicionando o diretório onde se encontrava o arquivo de socket:

```
mysql.default_socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
mysqli.default_socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
pdo_mysql.default_socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Após a alteração, apenas reiniciei o apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412009/starting-with-zend-tutorial-zend-db-adapter-throws-exception-sqlstatehy000/2412064#2412064)

Comment: @rray obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Precisa configurar o `default_socket` no arquivo `php.ini`.

Para localizar o socket do mysql:

```
mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -e "select @@socket"
```

Localizado o socket, agora é so colocar o caminho no arquivo `php.ini`. Localize
`mysql.default_socket` ou `mysqli.default_socket` ou `pdo_mysql.default_socket` e insira o caminha conforme exemplo:

```
mysql.default_socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
mysqli.default_socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
pdo_mysql.default_socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```