# No such file or directory (SQL: select * from 'companies')' laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estou tentando fazer minha primeira API com Laravel/PHP.

Estou tentando testar com o **php artisan tinker**:

```
var_dump( App\Company::all() );
```

Porém, recebo:

> Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]
>   [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from `companies`)'

app/Company.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Company extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'website', 'logo', 'password'];

    protected $hidden = ['password'];

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];


    public function jobs(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Job');
    }

}
```

Meu arquivo .env:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:KMNas/3ovm6UNhdsafaNHbajwXwo0SrvyLEQ51A/0waE=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=""

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
```

Não entendi exatamente o que ele não conseguiu encontrar.
Minha classe? Meu bd? Minha tabela?

@Edit:

Minhas migrations:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCompaniesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name', 100);
            $table->string('email', 60);
            $table->string('website');
            $table->string('logo');
            $table->string('password', 64);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('companies');
    }
}


<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateJobsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('jobs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->longText('description');
            $table->string('local');
            $table->enum('remote', ['yes', 'no']);
            $table->integer('type');
            $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('company_id')
                ->references('id');
                ->on('companies')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('jobs');
    }
}
```

Comment: Esse erro pode estar relacionado a conexão com o banco. Dá uma olhada nesse post https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115790/uma-pdo-exception-ocorre-quando-é-utilizado-localhost-como-host

Comment: Isso acontece com qualquer model ou somente com o Company?

Answer (score -1):

Eu estava com um erro bem parecido quando ia rodar minhas migrations
eu toquei essa variável DB_HOST=localhost para DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 e funcionou aqui pra mim.